# Formula "IF ANY" (basically a for each)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I'm wondering if there's a formula equivalent of an for each statement.
I know this would be possible with VBA, but given it's an official report I'd prefer to make it macro-free.

---

Basically I have a column (let's say A) that contains when an invoice was paid
`

```
 |----------------------------------|
1|DUE DATE (TABLE HEADER, COLUMN A) |  (COLUMN B)
 |==================================|
2|1/1/2019                          |   =If any of the due dates are past today, trigger
3|2/5/2018                          |
4|4/5/2018                          |
```

Now let's presume we have the current date (22/2/2018) as you can see, none of these are past the due date.

I have a cell in column B with the following formula
`=IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(), A2:A4, "d")">0", "All invoices paid in time", "Invoice past the due date found"`

Issue is, `DATEDIF` can only work with individual day, not a range. Technically I could do it with multiple `OR` formulas -> eg.

`=IF(OR(DATEDIF(TODAY(), A2 "d"), DATEDIF(TODAY(), A3, "D")...and so on......`

but this would be only viable in my example, not in document with 500 due dates.
Any idea how to exute this?

---

**TL/DR: I'm trying to create a formula, for a cell, that if any of the due dates are before today, i want the cell to trigger to a different value**

Comment: sounds like a helper column problem.

Comment: Why not use MAX(date range)  at the top of the data and then wrap a formula around this to see if the max date is greater than today?

Comment: @Rawrplus So you are trying to Search column A and get all the passed Due date to cell B1 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, sort of. Enter the powerful world of *arrays*:

Suppose your dates are in `A1:A3`. And the test date is `B1`. `B1` might contain the (volatile) formula `=TODAY()`.

You use the *array formula*

```
=IF(SUM(IF(A1:A3 > B1, 1, 0)), 1, 0)
```

remembering to press Ctrl + Shift + Return to declare this as an array. Essentially the `IF` is evaluated cell by cell in the range `A1:A3`. That's remarkably `for-each`-like.

There are other techniques for this *particular* case, but the answer I give you is, I think, the pattern that generalises most readily.

Comment: Yup, i basically posted a more beginner friendly way with hidden column in my answer above, but for a proper formula this is the correct answer! :)

Comment: This seems a bit long. Same thing could be accomplished with this array formula: `= OR(A1:A3>B1)+0`. Still +1, just giving you a shorter alternative.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889: Yes, that's a better "kernel" function than the one I have. Why not put as an answer?

Comment: @Bathsheba Done. Didn't think it was necessary considering it is practically the same as yours, but since you mentioned it, I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `MIN()` function.  If `MIN(A:A)` is less than `TODAY()` then at least one item is past due.

Comment: ͏+͏1͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏. I can't think of a better way than this for this case.

Comment: @Bathsheba  It takes advantage of **any** means **even one**.

Comment: Yup, swift and working. Kind of fascinating how many different approaches there are to this!

Comment: @Rawrplus  I confess.........this is a very, very common way to handle over-dues and expirations in business apps

Answer (score 1):

Well Technically I found a way to make this work, but this is more of a workaround, rather than proper answer to the formula in question.

If you create a (hidden) column like this

[image]

with the formula

`=IF(ISNUMBER(DATEDIF(A2, TODAY(), "d"), 1, 0)`

Basically, the way DATEDIF works it tries to substract two dates. However, since Excel is not normally capable of getting negative dates *(exception with Date System 1904 enabled)*. If it gets a negative date, it will produce #NUM! error, so the `ISNUMBER` formula acts like a trigger criteria in this function.

Then we simply create our control cell

[image]

With the following formula

`=IF(SUM(B:B)>0, "ALERT: " & SUM(B:B) & " invoices are past the due date", "No invoices past due date yet")`

The way this works is quite simple. If our datedif triggers, it goes to 1, by adding (`SUM`) all the triggers together we achieve the amount of the invoices that are past the due date (invoices where the due date triggered). For better illustration:
Now, let's say 2/3 invoices would be past the due date, then it would produce the following result:

[image]

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: I like the approach *(+1)*.  It **is** useful if you need to **do something** about the overdues beyond just knowing if there are any...........the trigger column can be  used by an *AutoFilter*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this array formula:

```
= OR(A1:A3>B1)+0
```